# Is Ayodhya's location true?

Tags: ramayana, puranas, history, valmiki, rivers

**Valmiki Ramayana, Balakanda, ChaturVimsha sarga, verses  8-9:**

> Mansarovar is on Mt.Kailasa, and from Manasa sarovar flows a river close to Ayodhyapuri. Because this has originated from a lake, saraH, this is known as Sarayu.  And because it flows from Brahma's Lake it is a merited river.

The current Sarayu river looks like it comes from Rakshastal and not from manasa sarovar.

Also according to **Matsyapurana, adhay 121, shlok 14-17:**

> "Sarayu river flows west from Mansarovar"

But the current sarayu river flows south from Rakshastal. So if this is the case, how can we say that the current Ayodhya is real? and where is Ayodhya?

**Note: I do not wish to offend anyone regarding my question. Our current thirthas are as holy regardless of their authenticity and I respect their location. Being a Hindu, I would never disrespect any thirth just because they do not match with shastras. Many thirthas have changed locations and this is why I try to find their original location. Sorry if I have offended anybody.**

Comment: What is "chatur binsh sarga"?  Here is the link for complete [Valmiki Ramayana](http://www.valmikiramayan.net/).  Can you update the link in your question with Sanskrit verses? Also, Please point out exact chapters of Matsya and Vayu Purana.

Comment: @The Destroyer ChaturVimsha means 24th.. Chatur =4, Vimsha =20

Comment: @Tezz 24th in which Khanda?

Comment: @TheDestroyer it's here: http://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/baala/sarga24/bala_24_frame.htm

Comment: Where did you read Sarayu comes from Rakshastal?

Comment: The current Sarayu river comes from the Ghaghara river, which originates from the Mapchachungo Glacier, not from Lake Manasarovar or Lake Rakshastal.

Comment: @TheDestroyer In this link, http://www.tour-tibet.com/tibetan-maps/kailash-manasarovar-map.html a river that flows from rakshastal  into Nepal and is called Karnali. Karnali flows into india and is called saryu and Ghaghara. Anyway in China manasa sarovar is called "Mapam Yumco" and rakshastal is called "Langa Co".

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghaghara if you look at this link Ghaghara is known as "Karnali" which flows from Rakshastal (Langa Co), China. In a Himalayan range, any lake formed is because of a Glacier. Eventually this lake enters Rakshastal and exits known as Karnali.